# T-SQL Trigger Update Columns based on inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been working with SQL queries for a couple of weeks and I'm trying to learn and understand from my mistakes. 
I have a table with two columns `IsInvisible (bit)` and `Name (string)` and when one is changed to update the other one also like: 
- if added a * in front of the Name to set `IsInvisible` to 1 and if * is removed to set it to 0
- if IsInvisible is set to 1 to add * in front of the Name and when set to 0 to remove it

I've tried something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[updateInvisibility]
ON [dbo].[myTable]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN


UPDATE myTable
SET IsInvisible = 1 
WHERE Id in (SELECT Id FROM inserted WHERE Name like '*%')

UPDATE myTable
SET IsInvisible = 0 
WHERE Id in (SELECT Id FROM inserted WHERE Name not like '*%')

UPDATE myTable
SET Name = '*' + Name 
WHERE Id in (SELECT Id FROM inserted WHERE IsInvisible = 1)

end
```

but in some situations it puts two * instead of just one and I don't know how can I remove * in other situation.

Is there a way to update the columns correctly based on my query so far? Can it be improved in some way to not repeat the update procedure?

Comment: While you have an working solution with @GordonLinoff's answer you should rethink your design. Your `name` column contains more than one information (the actual name and a sign for visibility) and therefore violates the [First normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with a single `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE t
    SET IsInvisible = (CASE WHEN i.Name like '*%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        Name = (CASE WHEN i.IsInvisible = 1 AND t.name NOT LIKE '*%'
                     THEN '*' + t.name
                     ELSE t.name
                END)
    FROM myTable t JOIN
         inserted i
         ON t.id = i.id;
```

More importantly, you this checks if the name already begins with `'*'`.

You can eliminate the need for a trigger entirely by using a computed column:

```
alter table myTable add newName as ( case when IsInvisible = 1 then '*' + Name else Name end );
```

The value of `newName` is computed when accessed, so a trigger is not needed to update it.